# Compute the Galois group of L over K

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

> $\textbf{Problem}$ $K=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$; L=splitting field of $\prod_{i=1}^{p-1} (t^2-i)$, where $p$ is an odd prime
>
> $\textbf{Attempt}$ Since $(-k)^2=(p-k)^2=k^2$, we know that there are $\frac{p-1}{2}$ many irreducible polynomials among $t^2-1,t^2-2,\cdots,t^2-(p-1)$. This implies that among $1,2,\cdots,p-1$, $\frac{p-1}{2}$ are squares and other $\frac{p-1}{2}$ are not.

Then, the splitting field of the polynomial be $K(\sqrt{k_1},\cdots,\sqrt{k_{\frac{p-1}{2}}})$...

I don't know how to compute the Galois group...

Any help is appreciated..

Thank you!

Comment: It is about $K(\sqrt{1},\cdots,\sqrt{p-1})$ not $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{k_1},\cdots,\sqrt{k_{\frac{p-1}{2}}})$. Can you try with $p = 5$, can you construct $K(\sqrt{2})$ ? What elements are squares in $K(\sqrt{2})$ ?

Comment: I thought $K(\sqrt{2})$ be the splitting field of the polynomial with $p=5$.. However, I don't know for any prime $p$ the splitting field of the polynomial be a simple extension...

Comment: $x^2 -2$ irreducible over K since 2 is not square in K. $K[x]/(x^2-2)$ is isomorphic to $K(\sqrt{2})$

Comment: Is $x^2-2$ irreducible over the field $K=\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$, what does it mean about the quotient ring $F = K[x]/(x^2-2)$ ? So $F$ is an integral domain, a field ? What can you say about its multiplicative group ? What elements are squares in $F$ ?

Comment: Since $(x^2-2)$ is a maximal ideal in $K[x]$, $F$is a field. Then, its multiplicative group is cyclic.

Comment: Right, cyclic with $25-1$ elements. Let $g$ be a generator of $F^\times$. When is $g^a$ a square ? When $g^a \in K^\times$ ? So what is the splitting field of $\prod_{i=1}^{4} (t^2-i) \in K[t]$ ?